# Я пытаюсь создать fixture для базы данных, но при создании русские буквы заменяются на непонятные символы

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь создать fixture для базы данных, но при создании русские буквы заменяются на непонятные символы.
[image: Вот примерно такая проблема возникает при создании фикстуры]

Comment: Примеры `кода` лучше прикладывать в соответствующем оформлении - необходимый кусок текста можно выделить обратными кавычками, тогда он будет восприниматься как код программы

Comment: Добавьте сам код в вопрос. От одного json толка мало. Проблема в самом коде.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указывать параметр `ensure_ascii`.
Если для `ensure_ascii` установлено значение `true` (по умолчанию), в выводе гарантированно будут экранированы все входящие символы, отличные от `ASCII`. Если параметр `ensure_ascii` имеет значение `false`, эти символы будут выводиться как есть.

```
with open("file_name.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(text, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Данного параметра у меня нет, т.к. json файл я создал на основе данных в бд. Короче говоря я создал фикстуру чтобы через неё загрузить данные в бд